# triggering a gitlab merge request pipeline using gitlab-python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gitlab

I'm trying to write a python3 script that will trigger a pipeline on gitlab for an MR, I just cannot work out how to do it.

The following works fine for a feature branch where no merge request exists.

```
import gitlab
import os

# GitLab access token
GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN = os.environ.get("GITLAB_API_TOKEN")

gl = gitlab.Gitlab(private_token=GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN)


def trigger_pipeline(project_path, branch_name):
    """Trigger a pipeline for a project."""
    project = gl.projects.get(project_path)
    try:
        pipeline = project.pipelines.create({"ref": branch_name})
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Attempting to start a pipeline on {YELLOW}{project_path}{RESET} failed.")
        print(f"Exception output: {RED}{e}{RESET}")
        return False
    pipeline_id = getattr(pipeline, "id")

    return pipeline_id

project_path_input = "path/to/project/repo-name"
branch_name_input  = "refs/merge-requests/10/head"

pipeline_id = trigger_pipeline(project_path_input, branch_name_input)
```

*(I've pulled this out of a larger script and simplified it down to isolate just this issue, so apologies if there's something missing. Like decent error handling)*

The repo in question has rules in place such that if an MR exists for a feature branch then a branch pipeline will not run (based on GL best practices), so trying to start a pipeline on the source branch returns a `400: {'base': ['Pipeline filtered out by workflow rules.']}`

Attempts include passing in (where MR is !10) the following as `branch_name`:

```
refs/merge-requests/10/head
merge-requests/10/head
!10
```

Whilst nearly everything I've tried returns a `400: {'base': ['Reference not found']}`, the attempt with `refs/merge-requests/10/head` gave me `500: 500 Internal Server Error` which still isn't helpful, but at least made me feel like I might be getting close.

Full output of the final case is:

```
python3 ./pipelines.py
Attempting to start a pipeline on path/to/project/repo-name failed.
Exception output: 500: 500 Internal Server Error
```